# how have 2 div with same height?

Tags: css

This is My code :

```css
#container {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 width: 650px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
#left {
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid red;
        height: inherit;
}
#left img {
 width: 200px;
}
#right {
 border-color: #ccc;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="left">
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEYXFYtEKaqcM2_n4o1ppeWTJhzXjhIaooK76ArmSOkl_r1oE2nQCB-12J">
 </div>
 <div id="right">
   HTML provides tags for three different types of lists: unordered ordered  and definition
   Unordered lists are normally displayed as a series of bullet points; ordered lists are numbered; and definition lists
   are presented as a word or phrase followed by its definition, indented on the following line. Figure 10-1 shows
   examples of all three (the code is in lists.html in the ch10 folder).
   CSS regards the components of definition lists as block-level elements, so it has no special properties to
   deal with them. You style definition lists with text properties, padding, margins, borders, and backgrounds as
   required. Unordered and ordered lists use the same properties, but CSS provides extra ones to control the bullets
   or numbers alongside each list item.
   Using these extra properties in combination with the display property, it’s easy to convert an unordered
   list into a navigation menu, as you’ll learn how to do later in this chapter. Many designers now regard this as
   the preferred way to build navigation for their sites. This isn’t simply a design trick. Even without any styling, a
   bulleted list is a logical and visually acceptable way of presenting a series of links to other parts of a website.
   A series of nested lists provides a structured outline of a website’s hierarchy, with the top level indicating the site’s
   main sections, and the nested lists acting as submenus.
 </div>
</div>
```

height #right not fixed,and it is may have change.how i can put image height equal height right div, I do not want `display:flex` Because not support IE8-IE9?

Comment: using jquery you can do the same height of each box http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2014/09/css-box-height-same-each-div.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
 #container {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 width: 650px;
 margin: 0 auto; position: relative;
}
#left {
float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; width: 200px;
}
#left img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
#right {
 border-color: #ccc;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 15px; margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="left">
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEYXFYtEKaqcM2_n4o1ppeWTJhzXjhIaooK76ArmSOkl_r1oE2nQCB-12J">
 </div>
 <div id="right">
   HTML provides tags for three different types of lists: unordered ordered  and definition
   Unordered lists are normally displayed as a series of bullet points; ordered lists are numbered; and definition lists
   are presented as a word or phrase followed by its definition, indented on the following line. Figure 10-1 shows
   examples of all three (the code is in lists.html in the ch10 folder).
   CSS regards the components of definition lists as block-level elements, so it has no special properties to
   deal with them. You style definition lists with text properties, padding, margins, borders, and backgrounds as
   required. Unordered and ordered lists use the same properties, but CSS provides extra ones to control the bullets
   or numbers alongside each list item.
   Using these extra properties in combination with the display property, it’s easy to convert an unordered
   list into a navigation menu, as you’ll learn how to do later in this chapter. Many designers now regard this as
 
 </div>
</div>
```

Try this

Answer (score 4):

**Try this code**

use `display:table-cell`

```css
#container {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 width: 650px;
 margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
#left {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: inherit;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#left img {
 width: 200px;
}
#right {
    border-color: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 15px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="left">
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEYXFYtEKaqcM2_n4o1ppeWTJhzXjhIaooK76ArmSOkl_r1oE2nQCB-12J">
 </div>
 <div id="right">
   HTML provides tags for three different types of lists: unordered ordered  and definition
   Unordered lists are normally displayed as a series of bullet points; ordered lists are numbered; and definition lists
   are presented as a word or phrase followed by its definition, indented on the following line. Figure 10-1 shows
   examples of all three (the code is in lists.html in the ch10 folder).
   CSS regards the components of definition lists as block-level elements, so it has no special properties to
   deal with them. You style definition lists with text properties, padding, margins, borders, and backgrounds as
   required. Unordered and ordered lists use the same properties, but CSS provides extra ones to control the bullets
   or numbers alongside each list item.
   Using these extra properties in combination with the display property, it’s easy to convert an unordered
   list into a navigation menu, as you’ll learn how to do later in this chapter. Many designers now regard this as
   the preferred way to build navigation for their sites. This isn’t simply a design trick. Even without any styling, a
   bulleted list is a logical and visually acceptable way of presenting a series of links to other parts of a website.
   A series of nested lists provides a structured outline of a website’s hierarchy, with the top level indicating the site’s
   main sections, and the nested lists acting as submenus.
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
#left{
      height: 125px;
}
#right{
  height: 125px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: @ehsanAS you asked "how have 2 div with same height?", Somewhere you need to fix height , else use table

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 width: 650px;
 margin: 0 auto;
    height: 580px;//added new code 
}
#left {
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid red;
        height:580px;
}
#left img {
 width: 200px;
}
#right {
 border-color: #ccc;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="left">
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEYXFYtEKaqcM2_n4o1ppeWTJhzXjhIaooK76ArmSOkl_r1oE2nQCB-12J">
 </div>
 <div id="right">
   HTML provides tags for three different types of lists: unordered ordered  and definition
   Unordered lists are normally displayed as a series of bullet points; ordered lists are numbered; and definition lists
   are presented as a word or phrase followed by its definition, indented on the following line. Figure 10-1 shows
   examples of all three (the code is in lists.html in the ch10 folder).
   CSS regards the components of definition lists as block-level elements, so it has no special properties to
   deal with them. You style definition lists with text properties, padding, margins, borders, and backgrounds as
   required. Unordered and ordered lists use the same properties, but CSS provides extra ones to control the bullets
   or numbers alongside each list item.
   Using these extra properties in combination with the display property, it’s easy to convert an unordered
   list into a navigation menu, as you’ll learn how to do later in this chapter. Many designers now regard this as
   the preferred way to build navigation for their sites. This isn’t simply a design trick. Even without any styling, a
   bulleted list is a logical and visually acceptable way of presenting a series of links to other parts of a website.
   A series of nested lists provides a structured outline of a website’s hierarchy, with the top level indicating the site’s
   main sections, and the nested lists acting as submenus.
 </div>
</div>
```